# How do you add a SQLITE TRIGGER in ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, orm, activeandroid

I've only managed to do this using SQLiteUtils.execSql(), what I'd like to know is how I can put the commands inside the assets/migrations/.*.sql files. In theory it should be possible but I keep getting syntax errors.